# Invalid Schema Update during patch operation on existing table in Google BigQuery via Google API Client

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to update the schema of existing table using patch via ruby Google API Client.

Here's the code:

```
    def updateTable(client, bq, schema,dataset,table)
        result = client.execute(:api_method =>  bq.tables.patch,  
        :parameters => {'projectId' => PROJECT, 'datasetId' => dataset, 'tableId' => table},
        :body_object => {
                  "tableReference" => {
                    "datasetId" => dataset,
                    "projectId" => "mydataset-1",
                    "tableId"   => table
                  },
                  "schema" => schema
                }
        )
        puts result.body
```

end

Here's the error I get:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "errors": [
          {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid",
            "message": "Invalid schema update. Field a_b_testing_group is missing in new schema"
          }
       ],
        "code": 400,
       "message": "Invalid schema update. Field a_b_testing_group is missing in new schema"
```

}
}

I'll appreciate any pointers, suggestions.
Thanks,

Here's a sample schema:

```
{ "fields" : [
    { "fields" : [ 
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "time",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "attempts",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "mode",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "distinct_id",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "waited",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "party_size",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "version",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "region",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "reachability",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "device",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "_os",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "a_b_testing_group",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "item_name",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "price",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "contestant",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "mp_country_code",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "_city",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "_region",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "source",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "label",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "sku",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "balance__soft_",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "balance__hard_",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "price__soft_",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "free",
          "type" : "BOOLEAN"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "price__hard_",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "magical_damage_dealt",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "magical_damage_dealt__players_",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "player_kills",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "damage_taken",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "duration",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "items_consumed",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "magical_damage_taken",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "physical_damage_dealt__players_",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "disconnects",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "items_sold",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "physical_damage_taken",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "healing_done",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "matches",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "relic",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "assists",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "largest_kill_streak",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "bots",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "gold",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "largest_multi_kill",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "ping",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "team",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "tribute_kills",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "connects",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "deaths",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "shrine_captures",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "spawns",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "items_bought",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "physical_damage_dealt",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "abandoned",
          "type" : "BOOLEAN"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "damage_dealt",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "damage_dealt__players_",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "level",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "party_muted",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "quests_completed",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "tower_kills",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "victorious",
          "type" : "BOOLEAN"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "name",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "response",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "type",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "currency_type",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "state",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "last_quest",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "product",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "amount",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "platform",
          "type" : "STRING"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "newbie",
          "type" : "BOOLEAN"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "campaign_id",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        },
        { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
          "name" : "delivery_id",
          "type" : "FLOAT"
        }
      ],
    "mode" : "NULLABLE",
    "name" : "properties",
    "type" : "RECORD"
  },
  { "mode" : "NULLABLE",
    "name" : "event",
    "type" : "STRING"
  }
] }
```

Comment: are you trying to remove a column?

Comment: I'm not trying to remove a column. I'm sending new set of data which has a few additional columns as well as a few columns missing which were present in the original schema. I believe BigQuery requires me to merge the schemas to have a super set of the two schemas as a part of the patch request.

Comment: that's it! adding answer :)

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports adding columns to existing tables, but not removing existing ones.

To prevent the error shown, when patching a table schema, always include existing columns in the new schema, and only add columns to it.

Comment: I get it. However it seems very unnecessary. It requires apps to pull the schema from bigquery and do a nested tree merge on the two schemas. Does google api client or bq client support this out of the box? Or the merges must be done manually?

Comment: not that I know of, but sounds like an interesting feature - can you describe more about the schemas you are changing? (seems its more complex than a flat table)

Comment: Yes. its nested trees of fields that are arrays. I want to share a sample schema but since commenting on SO allows only a few characters, I've edited the original question with the schema.

Comment: Does BigQuery supoprt change data type to existing tables and columns?

Comment: you can re-materialize the table - please open a new question if you want a detail answer